# Javascript - Cannot set property of method undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var Bob = function() {

  bob.hey = function (string) {
      return "";
  };

};

var bob = new Bob();

bob.hey('Hi.');
```

The above code returns "TypeError: Cannot set property of 'hey' undefined". What's wrong?

Comment: bob !== Bob and I do not think that code is what you want...

Comment: Why are you returning `""` and not using the parameter passed in?

Comment: *"What's wrong?"* as the error implies, `bob` is not defined inside `Bob`. Why did you expect this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to use `this` inside the definition of `Bob`:

```
var Bob = function() {

  this.hey = function (string) {
      return "";
  };

};

var bob = new Bob();

bob.hey('Hi.');
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point in your code, the variable `bob` is not defined yet:

```
bob.hey = function (string) {
```

Instead, you should use `this` to reference the current object:

```
this.hey = function (string) {
```

Answer (score 1):

From inside the var just reference the variable as `this` because `bob` is not defined...

```
bob.hey = function (string) {
```

Should be...

```
this.hey = function (string) {
```